# move_uploaded_file() not moving uploaded files

Tags: php

I have trouble in moving the uploaded files (image in this case) to the specified folder. When the user submitted the data, the path with the filename of the image is filled in the database, but the image selected won't move to the specified folder. I'm new to this as I followed tutorials on the web. But now it's just the file won't move to the specified folder.

Here's the HTML form :

```
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input id="imageSelect" name="profile" type=
    "file">
    <input class="submitButton" id="uploadimg" name="uploadimg" type=
    "submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

PHP Form :

```
  if (isset($_FILES['profile']) === true) {
          if (empty($_FILES['profile']['name']) === true) {
              ?><script type='text/javascript'>alert('Please select an image before submitting!');</script><?
          } else {
              $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png');

              $file_name = $_FILES['profile']['name'];
              $file_extn = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file_name)));
              $file_temp = $_FILES['profile']['tmp_name'];

              if (in_array($file_extn, $allowed) === true) {
                  change_profile_image($session_id, $file_temp, $file_extn);


                    header('Location: profileimgchange.php');
                    exit();
              } else {
                  ?><script type='text/javascript'>alert('Incorrect file type! Only jpeg, jpg, gif and png are allowed');</script><?
              }
          }
      }
```

change_profile_image function :

```
function change_profile_image($user_id, $file_temp, $file_extn) {
$file_path = 'Image/ServerData/Images/ProfilePicture/' . substr(md5(time()), 0, 10) . '.' . $file_extn;

move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $file_path);
mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `profileimg` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($file_path) . "' WHERE `user_id` = " . (int)$user_id);
}
```

The function script (if this helps) is located at:

```
Core > System > Users.php
```

The image folder is outside of Core folder which is

```
Image > ServerData > Images > ProfilePicture
```

I hope this information is enough. Thank you

Comment: have you checked the permissions?

Comment: Yes, I have change the folder path with `chmod -Rf 777` but it didn't worked

Comment: Try with `/`  here `$file_path = '/Image/ServerData/Images/ProfilePicture/'`; just fix the `$file_path` it seems to be wrong.

Comment: @Rishi I have tried that too, but no luck

Comment: give absolute path and check ?

Comment: give the full permission to the folder

Comment: Make sure you have `error_reporting(E_ALL)` enabled. What error is it getting when i tries to move the file?

Comment: @Rishi using absolute path works perfectly. So weird.

Answer (score 0):

`$file_path` is being interpreted relative to the directory containing the script, so it's trying to put the file in `Core/System/Image/ServerData/Images/ProfilePicture/`. You need to go up 2 levels to get to to root.

```
$file_path = '../../Image/ServerData/Images/ProfilePicture/' . substr(md5(time()), 0, 10) . '.' . $file_extn;
```

If that's not right, use an absolute path.

Comment: Then try using an absolute path instead.

Comment: yes it's work! So weird why using absolute path works when it's clearly everything is already checked even when using relative path?

Answer (score 0):

This one is working :)

```
if(isset($_POST['uploadimg'])){
$target_dir = "assets/uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["profile"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$check = getimagesize($_FILES["profile"]["tmp_name"]);
if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
} else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["profile"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["profile"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["profile"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input id="imageSelect" name="profile" type="file">
    <input class="submitButton" id="uploadimg" name="uploadimg" type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have fixed it! :D